# How to send docker commands to a container on another machine?

Tags: docker

Consider, my local machine is named `mylocal` and the remote machines are named `myremote1`, `myremote2`, `myremote3`, `myremote4`. I need to send docker commands to the remote machines to manage the containers. Is there a way I can easily manage these containers from my local machine?

Comment: Have you checked [Docker Engine API (v1.26)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.26/)?

Comment: Do have docker engine bound to port 2376 with TLS? (Or 2375 without TLS if you can risk it)

Comment: Sure this is a good idea? Why not simply enable a Docker Swarm instead? https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/  Alternative options like kubernetes (used to manage a fleet of docker hosts) are also getting simpler to setup and more common place https://kubernetes.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily achieved by exposing your docker server using Port listening. There are two ways to do it

Check the below URL

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-socket-option

**Listening on All Interfaces**

You update the docker service to listen on all interfaces by adding `-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376`. In this case you can execute command from your system to the remote machine by setting the DOCKER_HOST

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://<remotemachine1ip>:2376
docker run -it busybox
```

This will run the busybox container on your remote machine and open a shell for you into the same. This is not a advised method because if the IPs are publicly accessible, then some one can just hack in to your system and get full access to it.

**Listening on Local Interfaces**

A better way to do it is to listen on local interfaces. So you add `-H tcp://127.0.0.1:2376` to the service command. Now the docker daemon is only listening on localhost and isn't exposed.

So to expose that port on our system we use a ssh tunnel proxying

```
ssh -L 2376:127.0.0.1:2376 <user>@remoteip1
```

Above command maps the remote machine's `2376` port to our local `2376` port till the ssh connection is open. Once you close the ssh connection the tunnel also gets closed. So you can access the remote machine using `DOCKER_HOST`

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:2376
docker run -it busybox
```

The difference from previous approach is the IP we specify and the tunnel we create. A bit of more work but a lot more secure